# SQL Max from Subquery, Msg 102, Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, count, max

I'm trying to get only the Max-Results of the sums per day. I'm trying this with
Select Max(Anzahl) from (Subquery)

The Subquery itself works, but when I put it into the brackets, I get the following error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>  Incorrect syntax near ')'.

See below for the whole query.

Many thanks for any hints!
Cheers
Lukas

```
select Max(Anzahl) from
(
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), log1.timestamp, 104) as Date, log1.ID, count(*) Anzahl
from log1
inner join base on log1.ID = base.ID
where abc like '%test%' and log1.xyz = 3
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), log1.timestamp, 104), log1.ID
)
```

Comment: You need to provide an alias for your derived table.

Comment: `Select Max(t.Anzahl) from (Subquery) t`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL every derived table requires an *alias* so it can be uniquely identified, so

```
select Max(Anzahl) from
(
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), log1.timestamp, 104) as Date, log1.ID, count(*) Anzahl
from log1
inner join base on log1.ID = base.ID
where abc like '%test%' and log1.xyz = 3
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), log1.timestamp, 104), log1.ID
) as AliasName
```

Comment: Thanks Stu, that did the trick!